# question about the usage of 返 (Cantonese)

Tags: meaning, cantonese, colloquialisms, nuance

In the sentence 我已經做咗好多日，而家想放返幾日假, I would like to ask about 返. What is the difference between just saying 放幾日假 and 放返幾日假. What is the function of 返?

Thanks

Comment: i think it’s “翻”, not “返”; used as a quantifier (量詞)

Comment: [翻](https://cantoneseplus.com/admin/portal) is not a 量詞; 番 is

Comment: @TangHo, well, initially i’m also in doubt, after checking the 漢語多功能字庫, “《舊唐書‧敬宗紀》：「詔度支進銅三千斤，金薄十萬翻，修清思院新殿及昇陽殿圖障。」” i prefer “翻” to “番” http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=翻

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [番](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/553)

> [5] [粵] [adv] back; again; afresh.

放幾日假 = take a few days off

Depend on context

放**番**幾日假 (1) = take a few days off **again**

Similar example: 一年冇返工，而家返**番** = A year without going to work, now I am going (to work) **again**

放**番**幾日假 (2) = take a few days off **back** (for compensation)

Similar example: 舊年冇去旅遊，今年要去番次 = Didn't travel last year, have to travel one time **back** (for compensation) this year

> [返](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/171)

> return; come/go back